# Produce data extracts using day field for the Friday before the weekend

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, formula

Using TSQL on SQL Server...

I need to produce extracts that use a pay day column in a database that only holds the day number, for example 26 to produce extracts for the 26th day of the month with a twist if that pay day falls on a weekend then the data for that extract should be extracted the Friday before the weekend.

Has anybody attempted this and able to offer some ways of achieving this through TSQL?

Thanks

Comment: Are you always running this for the current month? Otherwise I cannot see how any logic is expected to guess what month you are running it for.

Comment: Hi, Yes this would be for the current month. The report would run Monday to Friday, any data from the next coupld of days needs to be produced on the Friday gone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have the month and year available too, in which case you can construct a real date, and get the day of week from it as a 1-based number starting at Sunday. So, 6 equals Friday. This will produce 5 for today, as Thursday = 5

```
SELECT DATEPART(dw, DATEFROMPARTS(2018, 07, 26)) AS [DayOfWeek]
```

**EDIT**:
I'll make another assumption, this time that this is somehow possible, like it's always run for the current month. This is a bit dodgy as it all falls apart if it's run too early or too late, but at least it's achievable.

```
SELECT  DATEPART(dw, DATEFROMPARTS(
    DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()), 
    DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()), 
    26)) AS [DayOfWeekThisMonth]
```

**EDIT 2**:
OK, with the understanding we are working on **this** month, we can do this:

```
DECLARE @PayDayNumber INT = 29; -- Replace this with a SELECT to get your value
SELECT CASE(DATEPART(dw, DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()), DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()), @PayDayNumber)))
            WHEN 1 THEN @PayDayNumber - 2 
            WHEN 7 THEN @PayDayNumber - 1
            ELSE @PayDayNumber
            END AS [WeekendSafePayDay]
```

For this month (August 2018) the 29th will return 29th. You can change `DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE())` for 9 to test September, which will return 28 because 29th September is a Saturday, or change it to 7 to test July, which will return 27 because 29th July is a Sunday.

Comment: No, all I have is the pay day field with a two digit number - no other date fields.

Comment: I'm looking to report on "pay days" that fall on the weekend on the Friday before. Could I create my own table with dates?

Comment: Then I don't see how you can possibly achieve this. The 26th July is Thursday, the 26th August is Sunday. Without the month it's impossible to know which it will be

Comment: Does this logic help?

F = Get Friday's date (day)
M = Using F, set Monday's date (M=F+3)
 Check if UC date is 0,  
if true/yes, Set data_flag to "N" 
else
    Check if UC date is between F & M
    If true/yes, set flag for pulling the data & use tenaltkey to pull the UC data that fall over the weekend
end

Comment: I've made another edit. Does that give you what you need?

Answer (score 0):

You have said in today's comment above that you are assuming the current month.

First turn your payday day number into a proper date:

```
select dateadd(month,((year(getdate())-1900)*12)+month(getdate())-1,payday-1)
  as paydate
```

and then use a case statement against it:

```
case datename(weekday,paydate)
  when 'Saturday' then dateadd(day,-1,paydate)
  when 'Sunday' then dateadd(day,-2,paydate)
  else paydate
  end as paydateadjust
```

(Obviously these will need rewriting into a proper SQL statement. Date formula borrowed from Michael Valentine Jones' super useful SQL Server date function.)